# JSON request jumping directly to error statement despite having response data sent from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

**Background :**

this is a simple ajax request to fetch data from database, my query and server side code works just fine.

**Problem :**

When i put the GET URL in my browser it shows the correct JSON response, but firebug (Firefox extension) doesn't show any response, and the error message is logged.

`alert('success');`  doesn't show

```
$('#loadOrderDetails').click(function () {
 var id = document.getElementById("order_id").value;
 var dataString = 'order_id=' + id ;
  alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "index.php?route=new/orders/GetOrder",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    alert ('success');
   // my code to show data in table..
                  },
                  error: function (req, status, err) {
                      console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
                  }
              })
          });
```

any suggestions?

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: And what is logged in your error message? Is the request path correct ?

Comment: request path is correct.
 it only shows  'something went wrong' , no status or details

Comment: **and what is the error?**?

Comment: and have you debug the code?

Comment: What is the address that you enter in browser?

Comment: mydomain.com/index.php?route=new/orders/GetOrder&order_id=1

@FarzinKanzi

Comment: Please test this: `data: JSON.stringify(dataString)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all, it seems that my problem was because of www , i solved it in server settings .